# Pandas can't read in excel file

Tags: pandas

Something is wrong with my pandas module. I tried to read in an excel file using the following code, which works on my classmate's computer, but it's giving me an error on my computer:

```
FFT1=pd.read_excel('FFT1.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')
```

The file named 'FFT1.xlsx' is in the same directory as my jupyter notebook. The error message says:

```
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7436/2793485739.py in <module>
----> 1 FFT1=pd.read_excel('FFT1.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    302 
    303     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 304         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    305     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    306         raise ValueError(

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    819         self._io = stringify_path(io)
    820 
--> 821         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    822 
    823     def __fspath__(self):

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     19         err_msg = "Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"
     20         import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
---> 21         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
     22 
     23     @property

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    351             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    352         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, str):
--> 353             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    354         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, bytes):
    355             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(filepath_or_buffer))

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     34             return open_workbook(file_contents=data)
     35         else:
---> 36             return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
     37 
     38     @property

D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows, ignore_workbook_corruption)
    168     # files that xlrd can parse don't start with the expected signature.
    169     if file_format and file_format != 'xls':
--> 170         raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
    171 
    172     bk = open_workbook_xls(

XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you already install openpyxl, if you don't try

`pip install openpyxl`

2. Change your code to

`FFT1=pd.read_excel('FFT1.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1',engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: I just got pandas to work by updating the pandas module

Comment: Wow hey is that you the real Arni? O.o